# check if a function is not false and use it's value without calling it again

Tags: javascript

Hi i would like to know if there's a good way to check if a function return something and have a fallback if it return false.

```
function setPage(hash){
    for(k = 0; k<magazine.pages.length ; k++ )
    {
        if( magazine.pages[k][2] == hash )
        {
            return k;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

var actualPage = ( !hash ? 0 : setPage(hash.replace('#', '')) ? setPage(hash.replace('#', '')) : 0 )} );
```

I'd like to avoid the setPage() function to be called twice while i can't store it's value before as i want it to be called only if hash is true. Is it possible to do it whithout sacrifiing the short syntax ?

Comment: `return` inside a for loop... That's new!

Comment: thanks for pointing mistakes, it's corrected ! but the question remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use boolean `||` (or).

```
var actualPage = ( !hash ? 0 : setPage(hash.replace('#', '')) || 0 )} );
```

Javascript utilizes [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) - `||` tests the expresison on the left, and if it is truthy, returns the value, otherwise returns the value to the right:

E.g.

```
var echoBack = function(v) { return v; }

echoBack(false) || 0; // 0;

echoBack('hello') || 0; // 'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make your `setPage()` method return `0` instead of `false` your problem is gone, while your method won't return ambiguous variable types anymore:

```
function setPage(hash){
    for(k = 0; k < magazine.pages.length ; k++ )
    {
        if( magazine.pages[k][2] == hash )
        {
            return k;
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
};


var pageNum = hash ? setPage(hash.replace("#", "")) : 0;
```